# Aviso: Intentando acceder a la compensación de la matriz en el valor de tipo bool en

Tags: php, array

Buenas tengo este error que aparece y la verdad es que no consigo encontrar la solución.

Es un sistema para mostrar si las clases son en  videos y si ya fueron vistos.

**Esta es la parte referenta al error**

> $array[$aulachave]['nome'] = $sql['nome'];

```
     public function getAulasDoModulo($id) {
           //array de respuesta

    $array = array();
            //session de usuario
    $aluno = $_SESSION['lgaluno'];
           //coge sas clases por  id del modulo em ordem de las clases
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM aulas WHERE id_modulo = '$id' ORDER BY ordem";
    $sql = $this->db->query($sql);
          //si ai algum resultado coge sas clases y retorna
    if($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
        $array = $sql->fetchAll();
                   
        foreach($array as $aulachave => $aula) {
                        //marca las clases vistas
            $array[$aulachave]['assistido'] = $this->isAssistido($aula['id'], $aluno);
            // si las clases son tipo video coge los videos por el id y pone los nombres de los videos
            if($aula['tipo'] == 'video') {
                $sql = "SELECT nome FROM videos WHERE id_aula = '".($aula['id'])."'";
                $sql = $this->db->query($sql)->fetch();
                $array[$aulachave]['nome'] = $sql['nome'];
            }
                            //coloca os questionarios
            elseif($aula['tipo'] == 'poll') {
                $array[$aulachave]['nome'] = "Questionário";
            }
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que intentas hacer ahí: `$array[$aulachave]['nome'] = $sql['nome'];`? Observa que estás declarando el bucle así: `foreach($array as $aulachave => $aula) {` eso significa que `$aulachave` representará cada sub-elemento de `$array`, entonces, ¿qué sentido tiene esto: `$array[$aulachave]` si ya dijimos que `$aulachave` es cada sub-elemento de `$array`? Explica lo que quieres hacer, si quieres modificar elementos de `$array` debes hacerlo de otro modo y además pasar por referencia.

Comment: @ A. Cedano lo que intento hacer es mostrar todos los videos de un tema en especifico dentro del aera de usuario. ejem: curso de html tiene 5 videos que los muestre tds y si en ese curso ai questionario que lo muestre tambien seguido de cada video correspondiente. Em este caso los muestra pero me sale el error desde que empece a utilizar php 7.4

Comment: Pues aquí `$array[$aulachave]['nome'] = $sql['nome'];` no estás intentando lo que dices en tu comentario. Ahí, si interpretamos el código, estaría asignando a `$array[$aulachave]['nome']` el valor que tenga `$sql['nome']`. Pero hacer eso no tiene sentido, porque no es lo que quieres, según dices, y porque además, como comenté anteriormente, `$aulachave` sería cada iteracción (fila) de `$array`, significa que `$aulachave` debería ser tratada sin hacer referencia a `$array` como haces aquí: `$array[$aulachave]['nome']` Prueba por ejemplo a poner esto: `var_dump($aulachave);` y verás lo que digo.

Comment: @A. Cedano hice el var... y me retorno null, he mirado en la base de datos y habia algunas columnas vacias al colocar info.. en ellas me retorno esto int(0) int(1) int(2) int(0) int(1) en el var... y ya no aparece el error. entoces creo que se a resuelto el problema que tenia, muxas gracias por la orientación.

Comment: Me alegro de que se haya resuelto. De todos modos considera optimizar un poco más el código, por ejemplo, el `SELECT` interno no sería necesario si lo incorporas en la consulta principal. Considera también las otras cosas que te he dicho en los otros comentarios, el hecho de que no dé error no significa que tu código sea correcto o que esté optimizado.